# Android - how to make sure the header fits all the buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a header that I am working on and I got the buttons to render in a single row, but one button does not fit on the screen and there is a space between the buttons.

Here is my layout for the header so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">


 <Button android:id="@+id/home"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Home"
/>

<Button android:id="@+id/questions"
 android:layout_width="0dp" 
 android:layout_height="10dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_weight="1"
 android:text="Questions"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"  />  


 <Button android:id="@+id/businesses"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Businesses"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/questions"
 />  

 <Button android:id="@+id/learn"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:text="Learn"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/businesses"
 />  


 <Button android:id="@+id/extra_help"
  android:layout_width="0dp" 
  android:layout_height="10dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="Help"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learn"
/>  
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make each button smaller, and make it so there is no space between them? Also, what is some devices have narrower screens? How do I make sure the header fits into all the screens?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `LinearLayout` and set each of the `Button`'s `layout_width` to `0dp` and `layout_weight` to `1`. That way, the entire space of the `LinearLayout` would be equally distributed among your `Button`s.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't quite work. Now the buttons just do not show up.  Here is an example of a button code I have now: <Button android:id="@+id/questions"
 android:layout_width="0dp" 
 android:layout_height="1dp"
 android:text="Questions"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/home"  />

Comment: Make sure you have an horizontal LinearLayout as a parent of those Buttons, also `1dp` tall buttons are hard to spot ;) Seems you went with `layout_height` instead of `layout_weight`.

Comment: btw what do you mean horrizontal linear layout as parent? You mean something outside the layout I posted?

Comment: I mean a `LinearLayout` (with `orientation=horizontal`) instead of a `RelativeLayout`... you should google for some information on weighted linear layouts to understand exactly how it works.

Comment: nope, cant get it to show up.  Just updated my original code with what I have now.  Maybe you could spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `android:orientation="horizontal"`, and you aren't setting `layout_weight` at all for those buttons

Comment: Where does that go? I mean the orientation..does it go in the top declaration, or each button?

Comment: Just looked it up...got it!! Thanks :)

Comment: just updated my layout again. This time they render side by side, but so high up, that they are 90% off the screen to the top :)  Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: You got it wrong, layout orientation is an attribute of `LinearLayout`. Also, there is no reason to set the Buttons layout_height to other than wrap_content, and the toRightOf attribute is now unused in that context.

Comment: Ah ok now it is starting to come together!! Thank you!  Last thing...it tries to make all the buttons same width, so buttons with longer labels become taller and take up two rows.  Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: No, not really... You could try using `ellipsize` but there are some known issues with it.

Comment: Cool, well thank you very much. You helped a tremendous amount :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. Than whichever screen you have it will fit in properly.